# setting the ExclusionFilter field for a TriggeredSendDefinition, and turning on the SEND_TIME_FILTERING business rule

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, account, fuel-sdk

When I attempt to set the ExclusionFilter field (a String) for a TriggeredSendDefinition, I receive the following error message:
`"The SEND_TIME_FILTERING business rule must be turned on to use an exclision filter."`

How/where can one turn this business rule on to allow me to use ExclusionFilter? Specific instructions (like what tab or API call would achieve this) are much appreciated!